# Enforce subclass behavior based on derived data

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to implement a "Range" class (in Java) to provide bounds-enforcing functionality to the int value it wraps. I want each of its subclasses to define their own min/max bounds without having to rewrite the logic that enforces those bounds. Here is an example:

```
public abstract class Range {
    // I would like each derived class to possess its own distinct instances of the
    // min/max member data
    protected static final int MIN_VAL;
    protected static final int MAX_VAL;

    protected int _value;

    public void set (int newVal) {
        // Range check the input parameter
        // this should use the min/max bounds for the object's most derived class
        if (newVal < MIN_VAL || newVal > MAX_VAL) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("`newVal` is out of range");
        }

        this._value = newVal;
    }

    public int get() {
        return this._value;
    }
}

// This class should limit its wrapped value to values between 1 and 6 inclusively
public class Die extends Range {
    public Die() {
        MIN_VAL = 1;
        MAX_VAL = 6;
        this.set (1);
    }
}
```

Obviously this implementation doesn't work, but how could I achieve my goal? Is this possible without repeating much of the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIN_VAL en MAX_VAL are constants, so you cannot change them.

Add two protected methods:

```
protected abstract int getMin();

protected abstract int getMax();
```

Subclasses implement these methods, e.g.:

```
@Override
protected int getMin() {
   return 7;
}

@Override
protected int getMax() {
   return 67;
}
```

In Range you then change

```
public void set (int newVal) {
        // Range check the input parameter
        // this should use the min/max bounds for the object's most derived class
        if (newVal < getMin() || newVal > getMax()) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("`newVal` is out of range");
        }

        this._value = newVal;
    }
```

Comment: Kudos for keeping the min/max bounds effectively static!

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to make the min/max values instance variables and have your subclasses set the range in the constructor:

```
public abstract class Range {
    // I would like each derived class to possess its own distinct instances of the
    // min/max member data
    protected final int MIN_VAL;
    protected final int MAX_VAL;

    protected int _value;

    protected Range(int min, int max) {
        MIN_VAL = min;
        MAX_VAL = max;
    }

    . . .
}

// This class should limit its wrapped value to values between 1 and 6 inclusively
public class Die extends Range {
    public Die() {
        super(1, 6);
        . . .
    }
}
```

Another approach is to define an abstract `checkRange` method:

```
public abstract class Range {
    protected int _value;

    public void set (int newVal) {
        checkRange(newVal);
        this._value = newVal;
    }

    public int get() {
        return this._value;
    }

    protected abstract void checkRange(int val) throws InvalidParameterException;
}

// This class should limit its wrapped value to values between 1 and 6 inclusively
public class Die extends Range {
    private final int MIN_VAL = 1;
    private final int MAX_VAL = 6;
    public Die() {
        this.set (1);
    }

    protected void checkRange(int val) throws InvalidParamterException {
        if (newVal < MIN_VAL || newVal > MAX_VAL) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("`val` is out of range");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding your first implementation, since all the min and max values will be the same for all values in the class, it would be optimal to use static data rather than keeping a separate copy for each instance, no?

Comment: Regarding your second implementation (abstract checkRange method), that kind of defeats the purpose as I would have to repeat code whose behavior is semantically identical to all types of Ranges. Having to rewrite it for each subtype of Range violates the DIY principle, does it not?

Comment: @weberc2 - It would be optimal to use statics, but you cannot override static methods. If you want to get really baroque, you might be able to use reflection to apply a range check only for instances of classes that declare a `MIN_VAL` and `MAX_VAL`. (You would then eliminate `MIN_VAL` and `MAX_VAL` from the base class.) That is no trivial matter if you want the presence of those values to be detected in instances of subclasses. Regarding the second approach, the answer by @asgoth is probably a better alternative.

Comment: I understand. Your answers did provide solutions I wouldn't have thought of initially (and which will prove useful for other problems I'll likely face, so plus one on that account); however, given how many instances I expect to exist for each subtype, I can't justify the duplicated values.